# How to use iterators in ModelBuilder to create new feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-database, iterator, model

I am attempting to use ModelBuilder to automate the process of plotting parcels of land that are related to mineral leases.

The existing lease feature class contains information related to reference document information, such as volume and page.

I am using a database populated with information pertaining to new leases, containing lease ID and reference deed volume and page.

Many of the new leases I plot refer to polygons that have already been plotted and refer to the same deed volume and page.

What I would like to do is create a model that will select features from the existing lease feature class based on the VOLUME and PAGE attributes in my database, copy/paste that feature into a separate feature class (editing layer from which features are loaded into the lease dataset), and populate the fields of the newly copied feature with the lease ID from my database.

I believe iterate row selection could be the best first step, but I am unsure where to go from there.

This is the most complicated ModelBuilder project I have worked on so any information or suggestions would be a huge help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is python using a cursor and dictionary to do the matching look-up and then output the result with an insert cursor to an empty feature class that has the same feature type and data structure as the original mineral lease with the additional Lease ID field from the table.  The code to do the look-up is incredibly fast this way.

Here is some code that just needs to be adapted to your data (workspace, input feature class, related table, output feature class, and field names of the VOLUME, PAGE, and LEASEID).  I assumed your data has a many-to-many relationship, where many parcels can have the same VOLUME and PAGE and many LeaseIDs can have the same VOLUME and PAGE, that way it will work even if you are dealing with a simpler relationship between the two data sources.  The output will include all Mineral Lease features, including those that have no matching LeaseID from your table, and all matching features will be duplicated to create as many features as needed to hold every associated LeaseID.

I assumed you wanted to output all of the matched lease features to a single feature class, but if you actually wanted separate feature classes created for each set of Volume and Page values, then that could be done with some minor code modifications, which I could provide.  I also could easily modify the code to eliminate the set of Mineral Lease features that have no matching LeaseIDs from being created if you don't actually want them.

I tested this code on my own data using a feature class with over 100,000 features and a many-to-many related table with over 130,000 features and it produced nearly 2,074,000 features that matched on the two relate fields I used.  It took just 12 minutes and 17 seconds to create that many features (a rate of about 10,000 features every 3 seconds).  Using a ModelBuilder iterator and repeated select queries would have taken hours or days to do the same thing.   My code does not even require the related fields involved to be indexed (but you dare not do your approach in ModelBuilder without first indexing the related fields).  If the unique values of my two fields had instead resulted in a One-to-One or Many-to-One relationship between the two data sources, then the code would have finished in about 2 minutes.

Open Python Idle from your ArcGIS Program Folder in the Python 2.7 group, open a New File, and paste this code into the new file then save the document with the name you want with the .py extension.  Then modify the inputs and field names to match your data and run the code.

```
import datetime

def hms_string(sec_elapsed):
    h = int(sec_elapsed / (60 * 60))
    m = int((sec_elapsed % (60 * 60)) / 60)
    s = sec_elapsed % 60.
    return "{}:{:>02}:{:>05.2f}".format(h, m, s)
# End hms_string

def timedif(end_datetime, start_datetime):
    seconds_elapsed = (end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds()
    return hms_string(seconds_elapsed)
# End timedif

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print "Script start: {}".format(start_time)

import arcpy  
from arcpy import env

print "Imports loaded.  Time elapsed: {}".format(timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))


# ---Variables that you need to customize to match your data---


# Customize the workspace path to fit your data, for example a geodatabase
workspace = r"C:\Users\CRID\Documents\ArcGIS\YourGeodatabase.gdb"
env.workspace = workspace

# Customize this to match your feature class name (assumes this is in workspace)
inputFC = "MineralLeasesFC"
inputFCFull = workspace + '\\' + inputFC
print inputFCFull

# Customize this to match your lease ID table (assumes this is in workspace)
relatedTable = "LeaseIDsTable"
relatedTableFull = workspace + '\\' + relatedTable
print relatedTableFull

# Customize this to be the output FC name you want (assumes output to workspace)
outputFC = "MineralLeasesWithIDs"
outputFCFull = workspace + '\\' + outputFC
print outputFCFull

# Customize this to be the name of the field names for the VOLUME, PAGE and LEASEID
inVolumeFld = "VOLUME"
inPageFld = "PAGE"
relatedVolumeFld = "VOLUME"
relatedPageFld = "PAGE"
leaseIDFld = "LEASEID"
print "Variables loaded.  Time elapsed: {}".format(timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))


# ---Code You Should Not Need to Modify---


# Check to see if the output already exists and delete it if it does
if arcpy.Exists(outputFCFull):
    arcpy.Delete_management(outputFCFull, "FeatureClass")
    print "Deleted {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(outputFC, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))

# Create the output Feature Class based on the input
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace, outputFC, "POLYGON", inputFCFull, "SAME_AS_TEMPLATE", "SAME_AS_TEMPLATE", inputFCFull)
print "Created {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(outputFC, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))

# get the field information for the LeaseID field and add it to the output
fields = arcpy.ListFields(relatedTable)
for field in fields:
    if field.name.upper() == leaseIDFld.upper():
        fldType = field.type
        fldPrecision = field.precision
        fldScale = field.scale
        fldLength = field.length
        fldAliasName = field.aliasName
        # Add a field for the LeaseID
        arcpy.AddField_management(outputFCFull, leaseIDFld, fldType, fldPrecision, fldScale, fldLength, fldAliasName)
        print "Added {} Field.  Time elapsed: {}".format(leaseIDFld, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))

# Set up the relatedTable field list
relatedFieldsList = [relatedVolumeFld, relatedPageFld, leaseIDFld]

# Build a dictionary from a da SearchCursor from the related table 
relatedDict = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(relatedTableFull, relatedFieldsList) as searchRows:  
    for searchRow in searchRows:  
        keyValue = '{};{}'.format(searchRow[0], searchRow[1])
        if not keyValue in relatedDict:  
            relatedDict[keyValue] = [searchRow[2]]  
        else:  
            relatedDict[keyValue].append(searchRow[2])
del searchRows, searchRow
print "Loaded relatedDict from {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(relatedTable, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))

# Build a field list for the editable fields of the input and output  
inputFieldsList = [inVolumeFld, inPageFld]
outputFieldsList = []
fields = arcpy.ListFields(inputFCFull)
for field in fields:
    if field.editable and field.type != 'Geometry':
        inputFieldsList.append(field.name)
        outputFieldsList.append(field.name)
    elif field.type == 'Geometry':
        inputFieldsList.append("SHAPE@")
        outputFieldsList.append("SHAPE@")
outputFieldsList.append(leaseIDFld)
print "Field list created for {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(inputFC, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))

# Build a dictionary from a da SearchCursor  
inputDict = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputFCFull, inputFieldsList) as searchRows:  
    for searchRow in searchRows:  
        keyValue = '{};{}'.format(searchRow[0], searchRow[1])
        if not keyValue in inputDict:  
            inputDict[keyValue] = [list(searchRow[2:])]
        else:  
            inputDict[keyValue].append(list(searchRow[2:]))
del searchRows, searchRow
print "Loaded inputDict from {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(inputFC, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))

counter = 0
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outputFCFull, outputFieldsList)
for key in inputDict:
    rows = inputDict[key]
    if key in relatedDict:
        for row in rows:
            for lease in relatedDict[key]:
                counter += 1
                if counter % 10000 == 0:
                    print "Has a lease.  Counter = {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(counter, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))
                relatedRow = list(row)
                relatedRow.append(lease)
                cursor.insertRow(relatedRow)
    else:
        for row in rows:
            counter += 1
            if counter % 10000 == 0:
                print "Has no lease.  Counter = {}.  Time elapsed: {}".format(counter, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))
            row.append(None)
            cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor, inputDict, relatedDict
print "Inserted {} Records.  Time elapsed: {}".format(counter, timedif(datetime.datetime.now(), start_time))
print "Script Finished: {}".format(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this amazing solution! It looks like exactly what I need. I don't have much experience with python so I would have never come up with this solution. You just significantly improved the quality of anything I could have come up with. Do you have any suggestions regarding what might need to be changed if I add variables to be matched to one another? (county, survey section, etc). This is a huge help thank you so much!

Comment: The field variables inVOLUME, inPAGE, relatedVOLUME, relatedPAGE, and LEASEID can be any field names, as long as the field pair inVOLUME and relatedVOLUME and the field pair inPAGE and relatedPAGE are two related fields with matching values in both the input and the related FC/tables.  LEASEID has to match a field name that you are transferring from the related table.  I could have made the variables more generic, but for my test I kept the variable names but used different field names from my data.  I didn't write the code to transfer more than one field from the related FC, but I could.

Comment: As far as adding more matching fields than 2 fields, you would need to provide two variables inField3 and relatedField3 and place them in the same relative positions in the field lists (usually separated by a comma) after the inVOLUME and inPAGE or relatedVOLUME and relatedPAGE wherever those occur.  One example, I would change part of the code to: keyValue = '{};{};{}'.format(searchRow[0], searchRow[1], searchRow[2]) and all current lines with searchRow[2] would change to searchRow[3].  Anyway, the code follows patterns, but I still had to test it for each section to catch code errors.

Comment: Technically, the inVOLUME and inPAGE pair and the relatedVOLUME and relatedPAGE pair could be named to point to just one field in the source and related FC/table.  That should make this code behave like a standard single-field join/relate without having to make any further code revisions.  Null values may cause some issues, since I did not test how they affect the key values of the dictionary, and Null values almost always cause value comparison problems when they are present.

Comment: I loaded your script in Microsoft Visual Studio and have pointed all the variables to the right place, but I am getting an error message:

Comment: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000012: Leaseid already exists
Failed to execute (AddField).


The thread 'MainThread' (0x15b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7064] python.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Comment: I deleted the add field part since it already exists in the output table (which was blank to start with but in real life will be populated with new lease data; in this test scenario it does nothing but in reality it is where new leases are staged before being loaded to the main feature class). After deleting the "add field" section it ran successfully, but it created 7844 polygons from my list of 300. So right now I am using a test dataset of 332 leases (small i know, but it's the first step). In some cases, there are multiple leases on top of one another that refer to the same deed vol/pg

Comment: What the script is doing now is creating a polygon for every possible match (3 leases with same vol/pg, 3 new polygons with their lease IDs). I think that by selecting the lowest leaseid value, it would ensure that only one polygon is copied for every new match. Also, not every row has deed volume and page (for both input FC and leaseid table), so every time there is a null or '0' value, it copies every polygon that doesn't have deed vol/pg. I will try adding an If statement that identifies these and skips them. that way, if I have a base layer dataset with 332 polygons, and an input

Comment: lease list with 150 rows with vol/pg information, only 150 new polygons will be added. do you think this is possible using your code to start with?

Comment: I said that Null values may cause problems, so the addition you are making to identify and avoid those records is fine (my test data had no Null values).  It is up to you to decide if you want just one shape and do not care about all of the lease ID values associated with it.  I told you I wrote the code to get every possible match, but an if statement can avoid that if you don't care.  I would normally care about all of the lease associations unless all leases but one are void.  Alernatively, if you want 1 feature but all leases, you could store a delimited list of leases in a string field.

Comment: The nature of one-to-many and many-to-many relationships is that you have to choose if you want an arbitrary match, a single summary record with a list, sum, min, max, etc of the related records, or you want to transform it into a 1 to 1 match.  I could not write the code to handle every possibility and the information you provided when I wrote the code was insufficient for me to design code that worked for your exact needs.  Your tests are the best way to find out what the possibilities are, each of which may or may not be valid depending on your analysis requirements.

Comment: All of the possible variations would use the basic form of my code, and my code handles the most complicated option (transforming many-to-many to one-to-one).  All other variations normally just need to bypass some of my subroutines, since the outputs you seem to want are actually simpler to create.  A summary value approach (list field, sum, etc.) would require some additional subroutines.  Eventually, I think I may adapt this code to create a tool with an interface for choosing the options for dealing with Null values, unmatched features, summarizing, and/or transforming the relationship.