# Working with related table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, table, relates

I tried to dissolve smaller features into larger (from unit to district) with field in related table. I can easily see the related records of related (many) table but unable to dissolved the features based on this (related) field. I also failed to do summary statistics of field at related table.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you are describing - perhaps pictures of a few records from the attribute and related tables will help - but you may want to look into using the Join Field tool prior to trying to Dissolve.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the schema of your data in database use arcmap in memory (map) join.

[image: In-Memory Map Join]

if changing the schema isn't problematic follow PolyGeo suggestion (Join Field Tool).

Comment: If you have 10.1 or later this may work.  However, you may have to also do an Export or Copy Features or some other feature class creation tool to duplicate the related features prior to running Dissolve if just joining the table and running Dissolve is not producing the results you expect.  Prior to 10.1 this will not work at all.  You can use a script to do the related join, but fast da cursors require 10.1.  Basically get 10.1 at least.  See my post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133496/how-to-use-iterators-in-modelbuilder-to-create-new-feature/133549#comment192342_133549